# Leaflet polyline popup has wrong Strava activity name and id

Tags: leaflet, javascript, strava

I want to display a popup on mouseover over a polyline which is a Strava activity.
And on click on the polyline it should open the Strava activity on the Strava website.

Both works but on many polylines it displays the wrong name and id.
Often multiple polylines have the same name and id.

If I insert a `console.log(data.name)` after `data = activities[i];` it prints the correct activity in the console.

```
var displayActivities = function(activities) {
var data = {};
for (i in activities) {
    data = activities[i];
    if (data.map.coordinates ) {

        var lineColour = "#FF00FF"; //magenta

        /* var lineColour = "#000000"; //black
        if ( data.type.toLowerCase() === 'hike' || data.type.toLowerCase() === 'walk' ) {
            lineColour = "#006400"; //green
        } else if ( data.type.toLowerCase() === 'run' ) {
            lineColour = "#0000ff"; //blue
        } else if ( data.type.toLowerCase() === 'ride' ) {
            lineColour = "#ff0000"; // red
        } */

        var coords = data.map.coordinates;
        // lat lon wrong way round
        for (ii in coords) {
            coords[ii] = coords[ii].map(function(x) {return [x[1],x[0]]});
        }

        // add line from toUnion array points to map with some basic styling
        // var polyLine = L.polyline(coords,{color:lineColour,opacity:1,weight:3,interactive:true}).addTo(map).bringToBack();
        var polyLine = L.polyline(coords,{color:lineColour,opacity:1,weight:3,interactive:true}).addTo(map);

        // highlight line on mouseover and show popup
        polyLine.on('mouseover', function(e) {
            this.bringToFront();
            var layer = e.target;
            layer.setStyle({
                color: 'blue',
                //opacity: 1,
                weight: 5
            });
            var popup = L.popup()
            .setLatLng(e.latlng)
            .setContent(data.name)
            .openOn(map);
        });

        polyLine.on('mouseout', function(e) {
            this.bringToBack();
            var layer = e.target;
            layer.setStyle({
                color: '#FF00FF',
                //opacity: 1,
                weight: 3
            });
            map.closePopup();
        });

        // open strava activity on click
        polyLine.on('click', function(e) {
            this.bringToFront();
            // Do whatever you want here, when the polygon is clicked.
            var url = "https://www.strava.com/activities/"+data.id
            //console.log(url);
            window.open(url);
        });
    }
}
$('#floating-text').css('display','none');
$('#floating-text').text('');
}
```

Comment: Scope issue. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work .

Comment: Thanks for the link Ivan but I dont get what the problem is.

Comment: The scope of `data` is outside of the loop. Therefore it's shared across all of the event handlers.

Comment: If I put `var data = activities[i];` inside the for loop (instead of `var data = {};`) the same happens

Comment: Now I have changed the var to let and it works! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have put `data` inside the for loop and changed `var` to `let` and now it works :) Thank you Ivan!

```
var displayActivities = function(activities) {
for (i in activities) {
    let data = activities[i];
    if (data.map.coordinates ) {
```